# wine wont install from softwarecenter

Tags: software-center, wine, software-installation

When I try to install wine I get following message:

```
wine1.2: PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.14.12ubuntu3) but 1.16.0.3ubuntu5 will be installed  
     Depends: ia32-libs (>= 1.6) but 20090808ubuntu26 will be installed  
     Depends: lib32asound2 (> 1.0.14) but it will not be installed  
     Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.6-1) but it will not be installed
```

and also a message saying that there is a possibility that software packages can't be installed both, is there someone who knows what may be causing this error?

Comment: This problem should only happen if you are using pre 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this from the command line?

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install wine1.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this when I had disabled recommended updates. Enabling recommended updates fixed this for me.